# SparkJobServer - is validate() always called before runJob()

Tags: spark-jobserver

According to the SparkJobServer documentation:

> validate allows for an initial validation of the context and any
>   provided configuration. If the context and configuration are OK to run the  job, returning spark.jobserver.SparkJobValid will let the job execute, otherwise
>   returning spark.jobserver.SparkJobInvalid(reason) prevents the job from running and provides means to convey the reason of failure. In this case, the call immediately returns an HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request status code.
>   validate helps you preventing running jobs that will eventually fail due to missing or wrong configuration and save both time and resources.

Can I therefore assume that `validate()` would always be called before `runJob()`?

If I load and verify the job configuration in `validate()`, can my `runJob()` assume it was loaded correctly and is available where `validate()` left it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct. See https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/blob/master/job-server/src/spark.jobserver/JobManagerActor.scala#L268